# Using FIRST_VALUE(), FIRST_VALUE() in MySQL

Tags: mysql

**I have 2 tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `post_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
  KEY `fk_owner_user` (`author_id`),
  KEY `idx_post_id` (`post_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_author_user` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

**and**

```
CREATE TABLE `Likes` (
    `like_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT DEFAULT NULL,
    `object_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `object_type_id` INT DEFAULT NULL, -- Посилання на тип об'єкта з таблиці "ObjectTypes".
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`like_id`),
    KEY `fk_like_type` (`object_type_id`),
    KEY `fk_like_user` (`user_id`),
    KEY `idx_like_id` (`like_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_like_type` FOREIGN KEY (`object_type_id`) REFERENCES `ObjectTypes` (`type_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_like_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

**I'am trying to get:**

- post_id
- text of post
- id of first like on this post
- datetime of first like on this post
- id of last like on this post
- datetime of last like on this post

**My sql:**

```
SELECT
  p.post_id,
  p.text,
  FIRST_VALUE(l.like_id) OVER (PARTITION BY p.post_id ORDER BY l.created_at) AS first_like_id,
  FIRST_VALUE(l.created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY l.object_id ORDER BY created_at) AS first_like_time,
  LAST_VALUE(l.like_id) OVER (PARTITION BY p.post_id ORDER BY l.created_at) AS last_like_id,
  LAST_VALUE(l.created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY l.object_id ORDER BY created_at) AS last_like_time
FROM
  posts p
JOIN
  Likes l
ON
  p.post_id = l.object_id
ORDER BY  p.post_id DESC;
```

I got result like this:

```
120 Impedit magni vero error ut.    72  2023-10-19 04:00:00 72  2023-10-19 04:00:00
119 At eum aut quibusdam ut.    1   2023-10-02 10:54:29 1   2023-10-02 10:54:29
119 At eum aut quibusdam ut.    1   2023-10-02 10:54:29 71  2023-10-19 03:15:00
119 At eum aut quibusdam ut.    1   2023-10-02 10:54:29 94  2023-10-04 11:54:29
119 At eum aut quibusdam ut.    1   2023-10-02 10:54:29 93  2023-10-03 12:00:29
118 Sequi dolor aut quis harum. 44  2023-10-03 10:49:20 70  2023-10-19 02:45:00
118 Sequi dolor aut quis harum. 44  2023-10-03 10:49:20 44  2023-10-03 10:49:20
117 Eos totam cum blanditiis.   27  2023-10-08 22:14:05 69  2023-10-19 01:30:00
117 Eos totam cum blanditiis.   27  2023-10-08 22:14:05 27  2023-10-08 22:14:05
116 Id quaerat quisquam quia.   15  2023-10-06 07:58:51 68  2023-10-19 00:00:00
116 Id quaerat quisquam quia.   15  2023-10-06 07:58:51 15  2023-10-06 07:58:51
```

For example, post with post_id = 119 has 4 rows.
How to get unique row of post_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default window for `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` is `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

you must explicitly describe the window range `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` :

```
  SELECT
    distinct
    p.post_id,
    p.text,
    FIRST_VALUE(l.like_id) OVER (PARTITION BY p.post_id ORDER BY l.created_at ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS first_like_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(l.created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY l.object_id ORDER BY created_at ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS first_like_time,
    LAST_VALUE(l.like_id) OVER (PARTITION BY p.post_id ORDER BY l.created_at ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS last_like_id,
    LAST_VALUE(l.created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY l.object_id ORDER BY created_at ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS last_like_time
  FROM
    posts p
  JOIN
    Likes l
  ON
    p.post_id = l.object_id
ORDER BY  p.post_id DESC
```

More readable/optimized version:

```
  SELECT
    distinct
    p.post_id,
    p.text,
    FIRST_VALUE(l.like_id) OVER w AS first_like_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(l.created_at) OVER w AS first_like_time,
    LAST_VALUE(l.like_id) OVER w AS last_like_id,
    LAST_VALUE(l.created_at) OVER w AS last_like_time
  FROM
    posts p
  JOIN
    Likes l
  ON
    p.post_id = l.object_id
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY p.post_id ORDER BY l.created_at ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
ORDER BY  p.post_id DESC
```

Comment: Not only is your second query _"more readable"_, more importantly it reuses the temporary tables instead of recreating them for each window function - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M9Eqrf6C). [8.2.1.21 Window Function Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-optimization.html#:~:text=when%20multiple%20OVER%20clauses%20contain%20identical%20window%20definitions).

Comment: @user1191247 great to know! Appreciate the information.